# What happens when tapping "Dont Allow" in the dialog shown few days later after "Always" authorization?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ios8, beta

This is the dialog shown few days later assuming that the background location like Region Monitoring was exercised (@see Session 706 from WWDC2014)
http://take.ms/wofmm

> "YOUR APP" Has Been Using Your location in the Background. Do You Want
> to Continue Allowing This ?
>
> Don't Allow | Continue

What happens if the user taps on Don't Allow - the authorization status is set to WhenInUse (kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) or to Denied (kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) ?

If the user taps on "Continue" will the dialog be shown again after other few days ?